# Run cleanup step if any it block failed

Tags: ruby, rspec

When one of my `it` blocks fails, I **want** to run a cleanup step. When all of the `it` blocks succeed I **don't want** to run the cleanup step.

```
RSpec.describe 'my describe' do
    it 'first it' do
        logic_that_might_fail
    end

    it 'second it' do
        logic_that_might_fail
    end

    after(:all) do
        cleanup_logic if ONE_OF_THE_ITS_FAILED
    end
end
```

How do I implement `ONE_OF_THE_ITS_FAILED`?

Comment: As a note: it looks like you need some other specs to depend on artifacts created by this spec - this is a big no no. Can you maybe explain the context why are you trying to do this? It's very interesting :)

Comment: @meta This is a very good hint, but none of my other specs currently depend on this one.

Why do I want to do this? I have a `before` in the spec that brings up a Kubernetes cluster. Then I test the cluster with multiple `it` blocks. In case any of the `it`s fail, I want to run forensic logic to poke at the logs of the machines.

Comment: @meta would you model this use case differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if RSpec provides something out of the box, but this would work:

```
RSpec.describe 'my describe' do
  before(:all) do
    @exceptions = []
  end

  after(:each) do |example|
    @exceptions << example.exception
  end

  after(:all) do |a|
    cleanup_logic if @exceptions.any?
  end

  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I digged a little into the RSpec Code and found a way to monkey patch the RSpec Reporter class. Put this into your spec_helper.rb:

```
class RSpecHook
  class << self
    attr_accessor :hooked
  end

  def example_failed(example)
    # Code goes here
  end
end

module FailureDetection
  def register_listener(listener, *notifications)
    super
    return if ::RSpecHook.hooked
    @listeners[:example_failed] << ::RSpecHook.new
    ::RSpecHook.hooked = true
  end
end

RSpec::Core::Reporter.prepend FailureDetection
```

Of course it gets a little more complex if you wish to execute different callbacks depending on the spec you're running at the moment.

Anyway, this way you do not have to mess up your testing code with exceptions or counters to detect failures.